# Whats the best way pull files to S3 using FPT/SCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Whats the best, light-weight, way to FPT/SCP files to S3 every few min?  So wget/curl could work.  Also a custom solution could work, maybe Java with DB to maintain the state.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use [`s3cmd`](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) or [`boto`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or the [S3 command-line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1710) or... well... quite a few other options.

Basically you're just posting to the S3 API. You can do it in nearly any language using AWS's myriad SDKs. `s3cmd`, however, is a nice, lightweight little CLI tool that's probably more than you need.

Your comment suggests you're looking for something slightly different. Here are a few recommendations based on the source and destination of the files:

- If you're moving files **from EC2 or your localhost to S3**, use [`s3cmd`](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd). If you need to run it regularly, consider a [cron job](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial). The following will run every five minutes.

  ```
  */5 * * * * s3cmd sync --delete-removed my_local_directory/ s3://my-bucket/path/
  ```
- If you're moving files **from S3 to EC2 or your localhost**, use [`s3cmd`](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) but reverse the syntax:

  ```
  */5 * * * * s3cmd sync s3://my-bucket/path/ my_local_directory/
  ```
- If you're moving files **from your localhost to EC2**, consider [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) or [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Comment: Maybe I should clear up the question but you can use those tools when you already have the files transferred to the EC2 instance.  My question is more of what is the best way to get files into the EC2 instance.

Comment: Ah. They should work from anywhere, as long as you've got AWS credentials that let you upload to S3. You don't need to `scp` from EC2 necessarily. You could do it from your computer, or anywhere really.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount S3 bucket as a local partition and work with S3 files as they were located on your server's filesystem. There are [a number](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) of [good](https://github.com/iij/s3fuse-fvs) Open Source tools available.

But from my side I would recommend you to take a look at my project: [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), a userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets. Project's goals and the main advantages comparing to other similar tools are: simplicity, the speed of operations and a bugs-free code.

Currently the project is in the “beta” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time ([RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) provides there an access to S3 located files to ftp / sftp servers).

We are building a community around our project and are seeking for more people to join our project to discuss future plans and help with the testing. From our side we offer a quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

A quick how-to:

You could mount a bucket using the following command (assuming you have installed RioFS and have exported AWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY environment variables):

`riofs http://s3.amazonaws.com your_bucket_name /path/to/localfolder`

(please refer to project's description and run `riofs --help` to get help with command line arguments)

Please note that the project is still in the development, there could be still a number of bugs left.
If you find that something doesn't work as expected: please fill an issue report on the project's GitHub page.

Hope it helps and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !